# Mysql Connector not showing in Visual Basic

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have installed
http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

So I am able to create a mysql connection. I have been watching tutorials and they tell me to go Project -> Add Reference and click on MySQL.data

However this does not show up anywhere. ( I have installed the Driver though :S)

Help appreciated. Thanks.

I am using Visual Basic Express 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to choose the DLL from the path where the installer have put it, so go to :

```
Project --> Add Reference --> Browse --> Choose the MySQL connector DLL File
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Hi Check your versions of the downloaded connector if you are using web developer 2010 express you will need to install the 32 bit version of the connector